# Прозрачный toolbar

Tags: android, kotlin, android-toolbar

Я хочу сделать toolbar невидимым, как мне это сделать? Вот мой Toolbar

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:title=" "></androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

И тема

```
 <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@null</item>
```

Проблема в том что от toolbar остается рамка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: а зачем вам его делать невидимым? Если он вам не нужен, просто удалите его, либо сделайте visibility = GONE

Comment: попробуй app:elevation="0dp" для AppBarLayout